# Kuala Lumpur Malaysia airport Terminal M to Klia2 and sleeping overnight at Terminal M

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit, sleeping, kul

I will traveling to Kuala Lumpur on Qatar Airlines which lands at terminal M.
After few hours I will catch a flight to Jakarta, Indonesia from KLIA2.

1. Transferring from Terminal M to KLIA2, do I have to pass through immigration first at Terminal M or terminal M and KLIA2 connected terminals?
2. On my way back I will be departing from at 7 in the morning. I am considering staying overnight at the airport. Is it possible to sleep at airport overnight? Are there any good places to sleep at airport?

Comment: Check this website, it tells you all the available options: http://www.sleepinginairports.net/asia/kualalumpur.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You will have to pass through immigration to get from KLIA (where Terminal M is) to KLIA2 (the low cost carrier terminal aka LCCT). Furthermore, you will have to take a very short train ride (or taxi ride) to get from KLIA to KLIA2. You will pass through immigration after Terminal M. KLIA and KLIA2 are not connected terminals. They are two separate terminals sharing the same runway and airport code (KUL).
2. It looks like there is a [Sama-sama Express](http://www.samasamaexpress.com/klia2) hotel at KLIA2. There also a few hotels near KUL.

Comment: Sama-sama is airside and most likely the OP will not be able to check in for the Qatar flight the night before, therefore would not be able to go airside to stay there,  They will be stuck in the check-in lobby, so are better off going to a nearby hotel.